# Display Specific Line Of Source Code in Popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm very much new to the whole chrome extensions world.

I've read through the tutorial "hello world" pages and tried to gain an understanding of content_scripts and background.html - but I may have overdosed and can't seem to find an answer to something I'm sure is a simple task.

In a tab a site contains the following Hidden HTML:

```
<div class="XYZ">
<input id="form_ID" type="hidden" value="REF_CODE#Product_CODE#Product Name#">
</div>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can Display the

- RefCode
- ProductCode
- Product Name

In a popup.html

I'm not looking at editing the html or manipulating it in any way.. it is strictly just displaying the hidden HTML - in an easy to read Popup.

Hope that makes sense..

Thanks in Advance.

**UPDATE:**

Popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function readIds() {
    console.log('Send request to content script');
    document.getElementById("response").innerText = "Requesting...";
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
       chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {cmd: "readIds"}, function(response){
        console.log('Response from page is:' + response);
        document.getElementById("response").innerText = JSON.stringify(response);
        });
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="width:400px;">
<a href="javascript:readIds();return false;">Click to read ids</a>
<pre id="response"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Content_script.js

```
// add a listener to get messages from background, popup
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.cmd) {
            case "readIds":
                console.log("readIds", request);
                document.getElementById("productID");
                sendResponse({refCode:1, productCode: 2, productName: 3});
                break;
        }
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  // Required
  "name": "WP Debug",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  // Recommended
  "description": "A plain text description",
  "icons": { "48": "icon.png" },
  //"default_locale": "en",

  // Pick one (or none)
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png", // optional
    "default_title": "WP Debug",      // optional; shown in tooltip
    "popup": "popup.html"
    },

  "permissions": [ "http://*/", "https://*/", "tabs" ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your popup needs to send a message to your content script which then gathers up the hidden field info and sends the response back to the popup.

Here is an example:

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function readIds() {
    console.log('Send request to content script');
    document.getElementById("response").innerText = "Requesting...";
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {cmd: "readIds"}, function(response){
            console.log('Response from page is:' + response);
            document.getElementById("response").innerText = JSON.stringify(response);
        });
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="width:400px;">
<a href="javascript:readIds();return false;">Click to read ids</a>
<pre id="response"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

content_script.js

```
// add a listener to get messages from background, popup
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.cmd) {
            case "readIds":
                console.log("readIds", request);
                //TODO: Get real values to send from page
                //e.g. document.getElementById("someid") etc
                sendResponse({refCode:1, productCode: 2, productName: 3});
                break;
        }
});
```

mainfest.json

```
{
  // Required
  "name": "Foo Extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  // Recommended
  "description": "A plain text description",
  "icons": { "48": "foo.png" },
  //"default_locale": "en",

  // Pick one (or none)
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "Foo.png", // optional
    "default_title": "Foo Extension",      // optional; shown in tooltip
    "popup": "popup.html"
    },

  "permissions": [ "http://*/", "https://*/", "tabs" ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
    ]
}
```

See documentation: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and examples Richard.. Will Test it out over the coming couple of days.

Comment: No worries. Please mark as answer if this answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Richard
I'm receiving Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement popup.html:1

not sure how to handle?..

Comment: Please update your question with your code and I can take a look.

Comment: Hi Richard - i've updated my question with the code that is currently in the files.. thanks

Comment: You code looks pretty identical - can I suggest you download my extension which works and try that and if it works compare to yours to see where the problem lies: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/63395529/FooExtension.rar

Comment: Gawd - Did my code work? If it does perhaps you could mark as answered? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Richard - was just going through some old items. Thanks for your responses - I was not able to get it too work on my side - but I found an extension that actually serves the purpose - however I've posted a question in relation to that as well.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810730/hidden-field-switcher-icon-button-option

thanks again for your assistance.