# Active tab's source code - get a variable-s value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have already written a Hello World example extension. Now I am trying to write a Chrome extension to get a certain JavaScript variable's value, if it is declared.

So let's say there is a

```
var test = 'a';
```

in the source code. I would like to get that `a` value.

**UPDATE:** I do *not* have access to the "original" website's code, but I know that this variable is always there, and has a certain value, always different.

An alert would do. (Can I alert, from the extension's page?)

I saw that there are things like "permission" and "tabs" and I am not sure what might I be missing.

I tried to search, found something similar, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173628/display-specific-line-of-source-code-in-popup) example just doesn't do anything when I click on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a content script, you can't have access to a variable declared on the page.

Taken from the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment):

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.

The only way I see is to load the script source via [XHR](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) in the background page and parse it. Then you may use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) if you want to send the result to your content script. Note that this solution won't work if the value of the variable has been changed by a subsequent script.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over that page you could put that value into a hidden HTML element on the page which your extension can then extract with a content script.

on the website:

```
var test a = 'a';
document.documentElement.dataset["a"] = a;
```

in the extension's content script:

```
var a = document.documentElement.dataset["a"];
```

Just make sure that the content script is executed after the script on the page (e.g. by adding `"run_at": "document_end"`in your manifest)

Comment: i do not have control over the "original"

Comment: You could look into the page's code and see if the variable is being added to  an element and check that element for that value.

However, this is a huge workaround which requires the code being written in that way. So if you want to apply it to "unknown" websites (meaning: no specific set of webpages that you know and can test against) this won't work either.