# Hidden-Field Switcher Icon Button Option

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've found this great extension which does exactly what I want in terms of functionality e.g it switches the hidden input fields and makes them visible.

The only thing I've been trying to figure out is how to make it so it will work as an extension icon button and not as a shortcut key combination?.

Extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hidden-field-switcher/gfkfklknjmlpldiggcjgdgkonoicfngp

Thanks

---

My Current Setup:
I've been able to add the button but on click it doesn't do anything:

**Manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "Display Hidden",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "Display hidden",
 "background": {"page": "background.html", "persistent": false},
 "browser_action": {"default_icon": "icon.png"},
 "content_scripts":[{"js": ["background.js"], "matches": ["https://*/*"]}],
 "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*"]
}
```

**background.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="background.js">
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {alert('icon clicked')});
  </script>
 </head>
</html>
```

**background.js** [Source](http://code.google.com/p/hiddenfieldswitcher/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk)

```
var allFields = new Array();
var visible = false;

function switchHidden() {
 if(visible == true){
     hideHidden();
     visible = false;
}
  else {
      showHidden();
      visible = true;
  }

}

function showHidden() {
    var allHidden = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var Key in allHidden) {
        if(allHidden[Key].type == "hidden") {
           allFields.push(allHidden[Key]);
           allHidden[Key].type = "text";

           /*for (var SettingsKey in Settings) {
           var subSection = SettingsKey.substring(7,0);
           var subKey = SettingsKey.substring(7);
           if(subSection == "styles_") {
           allHidden[Key].style.setProperty(subKey,Settings[SettingsKey]);
           }
       }*/

if(allHidden[Key].name)
     allHidden[Key].title = allHidden[Key].name;
      if(!allHidden[Key].name && allHidden[Key].id)
     allHidden[Key].title = allHidden[Key].id;
     allHidden[Key].style.setProperty("background-color","#CCFFFF");
       } 
    }
}

function hideHidden() {
    for (var Key in allFields) {
        allFields[Key].type = "hidden";
    }
    allFields = new Array();
}
```

Comment: Use [Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) extension, in tab "Forms" it has a "Display form details" option.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel thanks for the suggestion - but I only purely need that one function

Comment: `<script src="background.js">
       chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {alert('icon clicked')});
    </script>`

This won't work, you can't have inline code in chrome extension (besides you can't put code into `script` tag that has `src` attribute set). Move `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {alert('icon clicked')});` to `background.js`. Also, `alert()` won't work on a background page, use `console.log()`.